# Sortable table helper for MongoId

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm coming from the Cakephp world where there is the *PaginatiorHelper* that allows building sortable data tables quickly, and now I'm looking for similar solutions for RoR ***compatible with MongoId***.

So far, this is the only solution I could find:

https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid

Is there any other that is active and stable?

Comment: do you mind looking at kaminari gem ?

Comment: @GauravShah, that gem looks great, but it doesn't look like it allows sorting. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Raisen it does allow sorting